# understanding a simple return this in transit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively very new to js and basically I came across the following function in transit.js, a small animation library.  Have a look at the function below:

```
function Transform(str) {
    if (typeof str === 'string') { this.parse(str); }
    return this;
  }
```

Now `this.parse(str)`, is basically calling a fucntion which is attached to the prototype of `Transform`, you can see that function on **[LINE 422](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/blob/master/jquery.transit.js#L422)**.

Now my question here is about `this`, I have read a few articles online, which show how return this can be used for chaining, but I am not really sure in this instance what return this is returning.

When you say `return this` in this specific scenario, what do you specifically mean to return? what exactly.

I kind of understand that return this working a bit like so:

- you pass an object, variable or something to a function
- the function executes the steps
- you return the new object or variable using `return this`.

But I am still not clear, can somebody make this crystal clear for me, by taking my example and explaining using the examples context?

P.S. I am not asking to explain return this but I am asking to explain return this in the given context.

Answer (score 3):

The `this.parse(str)` most likely mutates the object and returns the now mutated result. This is useful, like you said, for [chaining function calls](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) like so:

```
var obj = Transform('some string').someOtherFunction();
```

`someOtherFunc` may be defined somewhere in the [prototype chain](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md), or by using some kind of [inheritance strategy](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-inheritance-patterns/), it may be an inherited or extended function of another "parent" object. The point is that when `someOtherFunc` is called, it is called on the object that is already altered by the `Transform` function.

Answer (score 2):

Transform in that context is an object that can be instantiated. Once instantiated, it has its own properties and its own lifetime. That is where javascript is unclear by using the word `function` during the declaration. (ES6 brings many better solutions relative to this usage).

```
var transform1 = new Transform("transform1");
var transform2 = new Transform("transform2");
```

transform1 and transform2 can now be used separately to call all sub-methods of the Transform object.

The Transform function can be seen as a "constructor" (though it is not the official way of using class in javascript). Without `return this`, transform1 and transform2 would be undefined. It is more used here to keep a reference of the newly created object than real chaining which is used more is sub-methods to do something like :

```
transform1.submethod1().submethod2();
```